# Bash function: Execute $@ command with each argument in sequence executed separately

Tags: bash, terminal, seq

This is an example function:

```
function example { echo "TextBefore $@ TextAfter" ; }
```

This is the command using the function:

```
example A{1..5}B
```

#### The output:

```
TextBefore A1B A2B A3B A4B A5B TextAfter
```

#### How I want it to be:

```
TextBefore A1B TextAfter
TextBefore A2B TextAfter
TextBefore A3B TextAfter
TextBefore A4B TextAfter
TextBefore A5B TextAfter
```

That's as good as I can describe it. If you understand it and know a better way of describing it, please edit the question.

How can I make each [insert word here] in the sequence being executed separately, as shown in that example?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Note that `function funcname {` is legacy ksh function declaration syntax -- a pre-POSIX convention that bash partially supports for backwards compatibility (without implementing the special behavior around locals that ksh associated with this syntax); for new code, `example() { ...; }` should be strongly considered for use instead. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf` rather than `echo`.  The `printf` utility takes a format string as its first argument (which can *always* be a single quoted string), and this string would contain a placeholder for your other arguments:

```
printf 'TextBefore %s TextAfter\n' "$@"
```

The arguments in `"$@"` would be inserted in the position given by `%s`. Since there is only one `%s` placeholder in the format string, the format string will be reused for each argument in turn.  This is different from how `printf` works in other languages.

Note that `printf` does not output a terminating newline by default.

Example:

```
$ printf 'AAA %s BBB\n' 1 2 3 4 5
AAA 1 BBB
AAA 2 BBB
AAA 3 BBB
AAA 4 BBB
AAA 5 BBB
```

If there are more placeholders in the formatting string, these will be filled in turn by the arguments given to `printf`.  The formatting string will be reused when all placeholders have been filled if there are still more arguments available.

```
$ printf 'AAA %s %03d BBB\n' 1 2 3 4 5
AAA 1 002 BBB
AAA 3 004 BBB
AAA 5 000 BBB
```

Your function may therefore look like

```sh
example () {
    [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf 'TextBefore %s TextAfter\n' "$@"
}
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
function example { printf 'TextBefore %s TextAfter\n' "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 3):

While both answers assume that the OP just wants to print the arguments, it may be the case that they want to pass the bracketed arguments to *other command* than `echo` or `printf`.

The shell has no `mapcar`, etc[1] so the only way is a trivial loop (replace the `cmd` placeholder with the actual command):

```
function example { for arg; do cmd "TextBefore $arg TextAfter"; done; }
```

As a sidenote, in the original `echo "TextBefore $@ TextAfter"`, when called with `$@` set to a `A1B`, `A2B`, ..., `A5B`, the separate arguments passed to `echo` will `TextBefore A1B`, `A2B`, ..., `A5B TextAfter`. That's one case where using `$@` hardly makes sense.

[1] there's `xargs`, but navigating through `xargs`' pitfalls and shortcomings is not worth the trouble in such a simple case.